# Find the source of a *nix process?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, process

I have a dev and QA web server running on the same EC2.  I've created a shell script (which is called via Cron) to check to see if a process is running and if not, restart it.

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

process="php"
makerun="/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/api/artisan queue:work --queue=high,default --memory=512"


if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process > /dev/null
then
  exit
else
  $makerun &>/dev/null &
fi

exit
```

This all works well and great but it's now time to start the worker for our QA server (the above is dev) and obviously it's not going to do anything since the process name will be the same in both cases.

That said, does anybody know of a way to determine what invoked the process? If I knew that one was launched from the dev path then I could rewrite the bash script to be much smarter and in turn monitor the process for both dev and QA.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: You run both dev and QA on the same EC2 instance? If so, I'm assuming dev and QA processes run with different arguments?

Comment: You could look for clues in `/proc/`. The traditional way to handle this is a *pidfile*: make the process store its process id to a file and check for a process with that id.

Comment: Could pass a different environment variable/value for production vs dev.

Comment: Maybe `pgrep` makes things easier. `pgrep -a php`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly: On my Linux systems, `ps ax` (or `ps -Alf`) already show the complete path of the executable belonging which has been used to start the respective process (at least in many cases). Why can't you use that?

Comment: @Binarus I was unaware of how to get that output, can you post this as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: I have updated my answer (added how you actually can get the last part of each line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem correctly:

On my Linux systems, `ps ax` (or `ps -Alf`) already shows the complete path of the executable which has been used to start the respective process (at least in many cases). Could you eventually use that?

For example, on a box running Debian Stretch (excerpt):

```
root@charon:~# ps -Alf
4 S message+   447     1  0  80   0 - 11283 SyS_ep Aug31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=syste
4 S root       468     1  0  80   0 - 11625 SyS_ep Aug31 ?        00:00:03 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
4 S root       674     1  0  80   0 -  3634 core_s Aug31 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
4 S root       708     1  0  80   0 - 17486 core_s Aug31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
5 S ntp        712     1  0  80   0 - 24467 core_s Aug31 ?        00:00:36 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 109
```

Hence, to get the complete path, you would have to grep the last part of each line, for example:

```
root@charon:~# ps -Alf|awk '{print $15}'
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon
/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
/sbin/agetty
/usr/sbin/sshd
/usr/sbin/ntpd
```